# PHP. MySQL. PDO

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, pdo

Есть  такой код

```
$data = array('Cathy', '9 Dark and Twisty Road', 'Cardiff');  
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO folks (name, addr, city) values (?, ?, ?)");  
$STH->execute($data);
```

Он вместо `VALUES` скидывает массив `$data`.
А есть ли метод, который передает массив не вместо `VALUES` а вместо атрибутов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пойти обходным путем и сделать вот так:

```
$fields_array = array('name', 'addr', 'city');
$fields = implode(', ', $fields_array);
$data = array('Cathy', '9 Dark and Twisty Road', 'Cardiff');  
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO folks ($fields) values (?, ?, ?)");  
$STH->execute($data);
```

В результате получится что мы вставили в запрос поля в которые потом вставим данные, решение думаю не из лучших, но если действительно так нужно, то думаю это единственный выход.

Comment: лучше не делать чистый `implode`. Представь если имя какой-либо колонки будет `limit` или `values` и т.д.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский маловероятно, что там может оказаться юзер-инпут. В качестве логики построения запроса, когда все поля определяются тут же и нужное варьировать их число, это нормальное решение.

Comment: @teran я не говорил про юзер-инпут. Я говорил о том, что разработчик может вполне себе сделать в БД таблицу с именем колонки `LIMIT`. Никто это не запрещает и это валидно. Однако при запросе выше, когда разработчик вынесет массив полей и будет имплодить - будет ошибка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский кто ему помешает экранировать сие слово?

Comment: @teran экранировать имя поля? ты сейчас про обратную кавычку или...?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в случае с mysql, да.

Comment: @teran эм.... так об этом мой самый первый коммментарий: `лучше не делать чистый implode` ....... именно с намеком, что если его сделать именно в таком виде - то может накрыться медным тазом..... поэтому его (implode) надо слегка причесать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский как по мне то `implode(',', [" 'limit' ", "field1"])` это тоже чистый имплод )

Comment: во, оказывается в коммментах обратная кавычка эскейпится обратным слешем `["\`limit\`"]`

Comment: @teran я думаю мои мысли были понятны)) надеюсь автор ответа понял и дополнит то, о чем я говорю, а также, надеюсь ТС тоже это прочитал...............`обратная кавычка эскейпится обратным слешем` - так это ж не новость :D

Comment: По сути надо делать как-то так (хоть и выглядит страшно): `$arr = ['limit', 'field1', 'field2'];
echo '\`'.implode('\`, \`', $arr).'\`';`

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь )